# Friction between bead and wire

Tags: classical-mechanics

A smooth bead is threaded on a rough horizontal wire (coeff friction, u) and free to move along it. The bead is subject to the following forces: its weight W, F1 pulling it along the wire and F2 at right angles to F1 and W.

Is the maximum frictional force between bead and wire equal to u multiplied by the sum of the normal reactions due to W and F2 ?

Comment: If you are talking about the vector sum of W and F2, then you are right

Comment: Yes, the vector sum. I ask because in a textbook only the reaction due to F2 was used to calculate the friction, the reaction due to W was ignored. Thank you.